# Installing Android SDK: Are the packagages asking for Login Necessary?

Tags: android, configuration, installation, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to install the Android SDK 2.3.3. using the Manager. I have selected all packages, yet some egregiously demand login information, e.g. `Open Sense` demands a login on `htcdev.com`, same with the Motorola packages, only it's a different site there.

Hence my question: Is it necessary to install those packages to start developing for Android? Does it work without? What would be the downside of not using those packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they just contain some custom AVD emulators. You´re fine without them!

If you want to test on an emulator you can create one with just a few clicks.

Comment: Agreed they are not necessary for basic work.  However it is not only emulator images - there are also the libraries necessary for accessing vendor/device specific optional features.  If you want to use those particular features, you'd need them.  But for writing apps for general usage you would not need them.